# Complex numbers - simplify expression to the A+iB form

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to solve the expression $$((i*(1+i))^n/((1-i)^{n-1}))$$ to the form A+iB. The answer given to this problem is $4*(-1)^{n+1} $, which is purely real. How much ever I try, couldn't get to this value, I give below my steps.

separating out , I get the expression$ = (i^n)*(1+i)*((1+i)/(1-i))^{n-1}.$

now $(1+i)/(1-i) = i. $

so the expression reduces to
 $$(i^n)*(1+i)*(i^{n-1}) = i^{2n-1}*(1+i)=(i^{2n})/(i))*(1+i)$$

now since $i^{2n} = (i^2)^n = (-1)^n$

so the expression $= (-1)^n*((1+i)/i) = ((-1)^n)*(1-i).$

This is the farthest I can get to, no way near $4*(-1)^{n+1}$.

Can someone help ? or is the answer incorrect?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The expression was very unclear in the original version and now it has become nonsensical.